# Adding hibernate-search to dependencies of existing system causes NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-search

I am currently in the process of adding hibernate-search to a big, existing project, but have already encountered a problem I can't seem to figure out.

My problem boils down to being introduced only by adding the maven dependencies for hibernate-search:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

As soon as I add this to my pom.xml, build the project and try to run it, I get the following exception (this is only the last part):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LATEST
at org.hibernate.search.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:213)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.createCleanFactoryState(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:280)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:186)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)
at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:520)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
... 123 more
```

So, first I just tried to google it, but it seems nobody else has ever encountered this problem in this setting before. So instead I try to dig into the code and see what this LATEST might be.

Following the exception, I find the following code:

```
    static {
        DEFAULT_LUCENE_MATCH_VERSION = Version.LATEST;
        DEFAULT_SERVICES_MAP = CollectionHelper.newHashMap(1);
        DEFAULT_SERVICES_MAP.put(IndexManagerFactory.class, DefaultIndexManagerFactory.class.getName());
    }
```

Then I check out Versions.LATEST, and it turns out there is no LATEST defined in Versions.

So my question is, since I assume this is a problem with my configuration, is there something i'm missing or have incorrectly configured?

Since I can't find anything about this problem anywhere so far, I'm guessing I need something else / more set up before this works, but I can't seem to find out what. I've tried following the getting started guide on the hibernate-search website without any luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a version conflict of your hibernate dependencies. What version of hibernate-core is getting compiled into the project?

Comment: @911DidBush We're using hibernate-core 5.1.0.Final the Version enum is from lucene

Comment: @911DidBush Just tested with hibernate-core 5.0.11.Final as it was mentioned in the hibernate-search getting started docs as the requirement (I assumed newer versions would work as well). Still getting the exact same exception.

Comment: hmm, the Version class it tries to call on is from  org.apache.lucene / lucene-core? The Version.LATEST was added in lucene-core 5.0.0. Maybe some module uses an older version that gets compiled into your project. You could try to add a dependency for a new lucene-core version, but I cannopt say if this won't break something else...maybe some other module in your project needs the old lucene version.... Those version conflict are a real pain to fix.

Comment: BTW. if you are using Eclipse and m2eclipse then the "dependency hierarchy" view is quite good for seeing what dependencies/versions will end up in your project. It will also show you when there are version conflicts (will display a "ommitted vor version conflict with xxx")

Comment: @911DidBush So what I was using, when I hadn't included lucene specifically, was aparently v. 4.5.1. So I now specifically include v. 5.3.x (tried all 3 minor versions) and now they all complain about Version.LUCENE_31. The exception comes from hibernate search according to the stack trace. I also found on sourceforge that hibernate-search 5.5.5.Final required lucene-core 5.3.x.

Comment: you could try using a older hibernate-search/hibernate-core version that works with lucene 4.5.1. Or you could try updating the versions of your other dependencies so that they work with the newest lucene version. Can't really tell what works without access to your project. Hope i helped at least a little bit by pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @911DidBush You definitively pointed me in the right direction, gonna keep going at it testing versions, going trough my maven dependencies with a fine tooth comb :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening to me with Hibernate Search 5.11.1 and i solved it by updating to Apache Lucene from version 3.6.2 to 5.5.5